# SwiftUI vs Interface Builder and storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new iOS development, I used storyboard and Interface builder to design my application UI. But now I am seeing that many people are using SwiftUI. I searched about SwiftUI and found some points about it as SwiftUI works seamlessly with new Xcode design tools to keep our code and design perfectly in sync. But I am not able to compare it with Interface builder & Storyboard. What are the advantages & disadvantages of SwiftUI over Interface Builder and storyboards?
Is SwiftUI will completely remove Interface Builder and storyboards?

Comment: The big disadvantage of SwiftUI is that your apps will only run on iOS 13 or later. Also there is a lot more information, examples and 3rd party controls for UIKit

Comment: https://twitter.com/MengTo/status/1217731240524046341
I will simply leave this Twitter post to you :)
In my opinion I started with Storyboard and I ended with simply coding is the best way to create graphic component :D
But SwiftUI is a great tool to deal with, try to learn it and you will create great things :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the interface builder like storyboard and `xib` you can see what you are doing. You take a component and then add it to the storyboard and that's how you design the UI, but if you do the same thing programmatically then it gets a lot harder as you can not see anything and you have to be experienced to do so. Every time you have to build an app to see the changes in the `UI` but `SwiftUI` solves this issue as it gets updated constantly as you write code. To solve this, Apple came up with `SwiftUI` which helps you to see what is going side by side. Anyone can move from `Storyboard` to `SwiftUI`.

Personally, I have started from `Storyboard` then moved to `XIB` and then I went to `Flutter` which was quite different and `SwiftUI` is quite inspired by `Flutter`. You have to keep in mind that `SwiftUI` support starts from `iOS 13`. You have to start from `storyboard` and then when you have gained experience then you can move to `SwiftUI`.

Update: Also, there is an another way of developing UI's and that is via programmatic UI coding. I have been developing UI's programatically for a long time now and personally it helps to understand the concepts of UI more and you can start adding a lot of extensions which will make your project easy to maintain at a later stage. When you develop in a group then interface builders throw merge conflicts a lot of time which becomes a pain very soon. (30 Oct, 2020)